# Process a link without a hash symbol using HashLocationStrategy (Angular 14)

Tags: angular, routes, location

An application using HashLocationStrategy does not handle links without a symbol №

I use a HashLocationStrategy in my application (it is necessary).

`providers: [      { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy } ];`

A third-party site redirects the user to my site, but does not specify a grid symbol at the beginning (for example, localhost:8080/login?parameters instead of localhost:8080/#/login?parameters).
How can I handle redirecting to such a link and redirect the user to the desired url?

I need to use the request parameters.
Guards in routes doesn't see this url

Comment: Can you elaborate why you can't access the full url in a guard or what else you mean by "Guards in routes doesn't see this url"?

Comment: @JineappleAra
if a'm use this code `path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [LoginGuard]` in CanActivate method shows empty url

Comment: You're using the RouterStateSnapshot.url like here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39747246/angular-2-get-current-route-in-guard