# Angular routing always redirect to home page

Tags: angular, routes

I've been spending far too much time on this apparently simple problem. I have a route, `page2` defined as follow:

```
// app.module.ts
import { Page2Component } from './page2/page2.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    Page2Component
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: 'page2', component: Page2Component },
    ])
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I've checked that `<base href="/">` in `index.html`. However, when I manually type in `http://localhost:4200/page2`, I'm always redirected back to the home page (defined in `app.component`).

I went over the quick start guide times and times again but could not figure why. What was wrong with my route definition?

---

**Edit:** I tested it with a brand new app (via `ng new test-app`) and new `page2` component (`ng generate component page2`). Still the same problem. I'm more confused the ever now.

Comment: Is this with `ng serve` or attempting to host the contents of `ng build`? If you're running into this problem with `ng serve` please post your full *app.module.ts*. If you're attempting to host the dist version, please see my answer below (updated).

Comment: show all your routes

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I guess you are missed adding  `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` to your App.component.html,

Add it in the app.component.html where you want to load your route component

Comment: This. Can't believe it is so simple!

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I already have the `<router-outlet>` selector in my app.component.html, however I'm still running into the same issue. What else could I do?

Comment: @LostAtSea the issue might be on your `href` attribute, if it's link to "", it will most likely go to home no matter what the value of your 'routerLink' is.

Answer (score 2):

I found the other post [Angular2 - app.module routing: blank path not redirecting to component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45305118/angular2-app-module-routing-blank-path-not-redirecting-to-component) to resolve my issue. When I switched from:

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent  }
];
```

to

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent  },
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent }
];
```

it started to work.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely problem is that you haven't imported the RouterModule or Routes.

Be sure to include:

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
```

edit: In the previous answer I included a possible other problem, but Routes doesn't need to be typed. If you've included both of these this is likely a browser related error (this happens on apache servers without route parameter forwarding enabled). If you are trying to `ng build` and use the dist files you'll need to enable parameter forwarding. See [this post](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed/wiki/Deploying-prod-build-to-Apache-2) on github. You should still be able to run your app locally with `ng serve` without problems.

Answer (score 0):

I was just having this problem while working on a large project and in my case it was that the route I was putting in my address bar had an ID at the end of it (e.g. `/my-route/123`), but my actual defined route didn't specify that there should be an ID (e.g. `/my-route`), and so I was just being redirected to the fallback route, which was the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Rahul Singh,i found the error in my code as well.

For me, the problem was not the absence of  in app.component.html rather the presence of other selectors for footer and header which were apparently fetching data from some services.
I commented those extra selectors and kept only router-outlet and the components started loading without refresh.
Fixing the other selctors was easy after i found the main issue,