# Angular 2 / Angular 4 : What is equivalent to AngularJS resolveRedirectTo?

Tags: angular, redirect, resolver, angular-router

In AngularJS route set up, I could use the "resolveRedirectTo" facility to calculate a value using an injected service, which I could then use in the redirect URL, e.g.

```
myModule.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) { $routeProvider
  .when( '/user/:userId', {template:'<my-component>'} )
  .otherwise( {resolveRedirectTo: ['MyService', function(MyService){
        return '/user/' + MyService.getDefaultUserID();}]
  });
}]);
```

How can I do the same in Angular 2 (or Angular 4, etc)?
Specifically, how to invoke an injected service so that I can dynamically create the URL to redirect to.

Comment: The [Angular routing documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router) is very good. I'm not familiar with angularjs so not 100% sure on what that code does but it looks like a [Route Guard](https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards) might do what you want it to. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39002288/angular-2-authguard-service-with-redirect) deals with how to navigate to any other page from within a route guard

Comment: The Angular docs do not address this feature from AngularJS. This very compact notation allowed you to specify, directly in the route definition, that you wanted to resolve a service request to then use that info to create the redirect URL string.  I see nothing close to documenting that scenario in Angular, and they apparently did not directly port that feature from AngularJS.

Comment: you can add a resolve or guard to the wildcard route like any other route, and guards and resolvers can both inject whatever you need.