# Using `UrlHandlingStrategy` to change location

Tags: angular

Is this a good strategy to redirect certain URL with `UrlHandlingStrategy` or is there a better way?

e.g. the bellow class implements `UrlHandlingStrategy` and will redirect ngJs url that contains a  #(hash).

The below works but I get the feeling there is a better way and the issue is the `class::shouldProcessUrl` is called multiple times.

```
export class HybridUrlHandlingStrategy implements UrlHandlingStrategy {
  constructor(private readonly location: Location) {}

  shouldProcessUrl(urlTree: UrlTree): boolean {
    const url: string = urlTree.toString();
    // handle #hash routing
    if (urlTree.fragment) {
      const fragment: string = urlTree.fragment.replace(/[#!]/g, '');
      this.location.go(fragment); // <------------------------------- redirect done here
      return false;
    }

    return /^\/(errors|angularIO).*$/.test(url);
  }

  extract(urlTree: UrlTree): UrlTree {
    return urlTree;
  }

  merge(urlTree: UrlTree, _rawUrl: UrlTree): UrlTree {
    return urlTree;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you ask if this is the right place then NO, because below is what is mentioned in the documentation.

> shouldProcessUrl() - Tells the router if this URL should be processed.

```
abstract shouldProcessUrl(url: UrlTree): boolean
```

So instead, its better you perform the navigation logic on a `guard` rather than on the `UrlHandlingStrategy`

[Reference Stack Overflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39002288/angular-2-authguard-service-with-redirect)